# Efeito scrollTo JS , fazer funcionar clicando no <li> e não somente no <a href="#">

Tags: javascript, html, scrollto

Meu problema é o seguinte, estou usando o plugin `scrollTo` estava tudo ok funcionando em todos elementos que eu queria no site.

Porem pediram para mudar uma coisa no menu, atualmente o efeito so acontece quando clico na tag `<a href="#">`, porem pediram para mudar, agora tudo tem q acontecer quando clico no `<li>`. Ok poderia envolver o `li` dentro de um `a`, porem eu teria um trabalho maior (acredito eu) do que alterar no `JS`, mas não to conseguindo, ja modifiquei o código abaixo algumas vezes e so funcionou quando no `html` eu coloquei o `href` na tag `li` (mas deve ser errado isso né).

Segue o código.

```js
 $(function(){
 
  var wrapper = $("#wrapper"),
    $menu = $("#menu");
 
  $menu.on("click","a", function(){
   var $this = $(this),
     href = $(this).attr("href"),
        topY = $(href).offset().top;
 
      TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:topY, x:0}, ease:Cubic.easeIn});
 
    return false;
  });
 
 });
```

```html
nav#menu.menu
 ul
  li.icon-play
   a(href="#home")
  li.link-empresa
   a(href="#empresa") playlearn
  li.link-tecnologias
   a(href="#tecnologicas") tecnologia educacional
  li.link-cases
   a(href="#cases") portifólio
  li.link-contato
   a(href="#contato") contato
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterei teu código para ser acionado ao clicar no `<li>` e procurar usando o `.find()` o elemento `<a>` dentro dele e recuperar o seu `href`:

```js
$(function(){
 
  var wrapper = $("#wrapper"),
    $menu = $("#menu");
 
  $menu.on("click","li", function(){
   var este = $(this),
     href = $(this).find("a").attr("href"),
        topY = $(href).offset().top;
 
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: topY }, 800);
 
    return false;
  });
 
 });
```

```css
.ex {
   height: 200px;
   background: #EEE;
   border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="menu" class="menu">
<ul>
  <li class="icon-play">
    <a href="#home">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link-empresa">
    <a href="#empresa">playlearn</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link-tecnologias">
    <a href="#tecnologicas">tecnologia educacional</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link-cases">
    <a href="#cases">portifólio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="link-contato">
    <a href="#contato">contato</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="home" class="ex"></div>
<div id="empresa" class="ex"></div>
<div id="tecnologicas" class="ex"></div>
<div id="cases" class="ex"></div>
<div id="contato" class="ex"></div>
```

Alterei o código para funcionar utilizando apenas jQuery, mas isso fica de acordo com tua necessidade/vontade.

Comment: Cara era isso mesmo, muito básico e eu quebrando a cabeça =/ ... Muito Obrigado =D.

Comment: @Erick não se abala que eu já estou há quase uma década quebrando a cabeça no JS hahaha ademais estamos aqui para fortalecer a comunidade, fico feliz em te ajudar!